# Progress in thermographic & atomic weight calculi for combinatorial games

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, online-resources

In Combinatorial Game Theory by Aaron Siegel the following are given:

> Question (page 150). Can the atomic weight theory be generalized to higher-order uptimals?
>
> Open Problem (page 151). Extend the atomic weight calculus to a procedure for computing aw(G) for arbitrary atomic G.
>
> Open Problem (page 299). Extend the atomic weight calculus to (an appropriate subclass of) stoppers.
>
> Open Problem (page 377). Develop a thermographic calculus that works for all loopy games.
>
> Question (page 409). Can the atomic weight calculus be generalized to $\text{PG}^0$?

**Has any progress been made in any of the above?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say I'm up to date on all CGT research, but I would assume it's fairly likely any significant progress would be posted on the [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/about) and mention "atomic weight" or "thermographic calculus" in the abstract. There are [no relevant math or CS papers](https://arxiv.org/search/advanced?advanced=&terms-0-operator=AND&terms-0-term=%22atomic%20weight%22&terms-0-field=abstract&classification-computer_science=y&classification-mathematics=y&classification-physics_archives=all&classification-include_cross_list=include&date-filter_by=all_dates&date-year=&date-from_date=&date-to_date=&date-date_type=submitted_date&abstracts=show&size=50&order=-announced_date_first) there with "atomic weight" in the abstract. There are [no papers](https://arxiv.org/search/?query=%22thermographic%20calculus%22&searchtype=all&source=header) with "thermographic calculus" in any arXiv field. Neither of [the two papers](https://arxiv.org/search/?query=%22loopy%20game%22&searchtype=all&abstracts=show&order=-announced_date_first&size=50) (at the time of writing) with "loopy game" in the abstract have progress on these questions.

So I would say the answer is **probably not**.